# Djange reverse() to an admin URL not working in management command

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls

I have a project (myproj) with several applications in it. One application (myapp) has a management command I'm struggling with. I want this command to send out an email that contains URLs to model instances on the admin site. But I keep getting this error `ImproperlyConfigured: The included urlconf XXX doesn't have any patterns in it` (where XXX is some number).

Everything else seems to work. When I visit the '/admin/myapp' page all my models come up and I can perform every action in them. So it doesn't seem to be an error in general with my url patterns. I have a feeling that the management command isn't loading the url patterns and that's why it's failing, but I can't figure out how to get it to do that.

Some abbreviated code. All on python 2.7.6. Django 1.5.5

### myproj/myproj/urls.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^auth/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # Other app includes, but none for myapp as it is strictly admin
)
```

### myproj/myapp/urls.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',

)
```

### myproj/myapp/management/commands/my_command.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        from ... import do_stuff
        do_stuff()
```

### myproj/myapp/__init__.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
# Tried: also reverse_lazy, just delays the exception
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def do_stuff():
    # Tried here: import myproj.urls

    # Work...
    # Exception here
    a_url = reverse('admin:myapp_mymodel_change', a_model.pk)
    # Work...

    # Send email here
    # Exception here if using reverse_lazy
```

Comment: `urlpatterns = patterns('', )` ... `ImproperlyConfigured: The included urlconf XXX doesn't have any patterns in it.` Are you sure that blank URLConf in /myproj/myapp is working? Why is it there? (You don't even have to have a `urls.py` if you have nothing to say.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arg. I'm an idiot. Should be:

```
reverse('admin:myapp_mymodel_change', args=(a_model.pk,))
```